# Serverless command "invoke test" not found. Run "serverless help" for a list of all available commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-plugins

I have my serverless.yml like below

```
service: omy-api

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'devint'}
  memorySize: 128 
  timeout: 15 

custom:
  jest: 
    collectCoverage: true
    
functions:
  - ${file(config/Customer/delete.yml)}

plugins:
  - serverless-jest-plugin
```

in my package.json I have

```
{
  "name": "omy-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "sls deploy",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": ["text-summary"],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": -10
      }
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless": "^1.83.3",
    "serverless-jest-plugin": "^0.3.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^27.0.6"
  }
}
```

am following the [https://github.com/nordcloud/serverless-jest-plugin](http://serverless-jest=plugin) documentation.
when i run sls invoke test, I get the error

> Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
> Serverless command "invoke test" not found. Run "serverless help" for a list of all available commands.

I tried sls invoke test --help, but I get the same error.

Comment: try from terminal `npx sls invoke test` or `npm run sls invoke test` or make sure you're following the docs: https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-jest-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run it by entering a command like below, you must first install serverless and the serverless plugins you use globally, for example

```
npm install -g serverless

npm install -g serverless-jest-plugin
```

and run

```
sls invoke test
```